# Alternating table rows according to field value

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

I need to write a code in which the rows of a table change their background color to differentiate from each other, but there's a catch: I need to do this not to odd/even rows, but to row groups in which there is a model field with the same value. Example:

```
Row 1: id = 1, field1 = 1, name = name1
Row 2: id = 2, field1 = 1, name = name2
***change rows background color***
Row 3: id = 3, field1 = 2, name = name3
Row 4: id = 4, field1 = 2, name = name4
Row 5: id = 5, field1 = 2, name = name5
***change rows background color***
Row 6: id = 6, field1 = 3, name = name6
Row 7: id = 7, field1 = 3, name = name7
```

In such case, I'd need to have the first and second rows with the same background color, and the third, fourth and fifth with another one, sixth and seventh with the first color and so on, to be able to differentiate both groups.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it always be this configuration? first 2, next 3 and final 2?

Comment: You could use a view model with an addition property for the color or class name, and then when creating the rows in the loop, use `<tr class="@item.ClassName">....`

Comment: @Cory, no, it was only as an example to show why the stripped css class wouldn't work. Every data group could consist of 'n' rows.

Comment: @Stephen, since I'm already using a VM to show the data, I can try to just add a field like you suggest. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery. Loop through all rows then based on a condition change the background color.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('tr').each(function (index) { //iterate over all table rows
                if (index > 0) {     //skip header
                     //Assuming your Id will be added to the first column. 
                    if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text() == "1") {
                        $(this).toggleClass("YOUR CSS CLASS");
                    }
            });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.  It's a little wonky, but will function.  This assumes that your `<tr>` items contain a `field` attribute (your question was not entirely clear on that) and that they increment (jsfiddle goes `1, 2, 13` rather than `1, 2, 3` just to show that it will function for values above 9).

https://jsfiddle.net/9k71jojo/

```
tr[field$="1"],tr[field$="3"],tr[field$="5"],tr[field$="7"],tr[field$="9"] {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}

tr[field$="0"],tr[field$="2"],tr[field$="4"],tr[field$="6"],tr[field$="8"] {
  background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

Relies on the attribute-ends-with selector: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp